# Executing a shared library

Tags: libraries, c

Some shared libraries provide an output when called from the command line as if they were executables. For example:

```
$ /lib/libc.so.6 
GNU C Library stable release version 2.13, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.5.2.
Compiled on a Linux 2.6.37 system on 2011-01-18.
[...]
```

In a shared library of my own written in C, how can I provide this output? I've executed now a library I just made and I get a `segment fault`.

Comment: Seems a topic for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Thank you. I'v now asked this there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963029/executing-a-shared-library-on-unix

Answer (score 4):

Try defining a `void __libc_main()` or `void _init()`.

Comment: Thank you. It does not work for me, code in `__libc_main()` does not seem to be called and I get a `segment fault` (perhaps before calling it?), `_init()` cannot be linked because this function is already defined by `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../lib/crti.o:initfini.c`

Answer (score 2):

I've just answered essentially this same question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68339111/14760867).  My motivation for figuring this out was to implement support in [`libcap`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/commit/?id=ee3b25c0a877fa74d1aec88f325ac45b09963c82) and [`pam_cap.so`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/commit/?id=efd293947f940180eedd8d0915b124f4aedccc08).

The key ingredients of the answer are: the `.interp` ELF section content which includes a reference to the dynamic library loader; the specification of a runtime entry point.

In steps (abbreviated from the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68339111/14760867) answer) you do this:

- figure out what dynamic loader is used on your system:

```
$ ldd $(which awk)|grep ld-linux|awk '{print $1}'
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

- construct your shared library source code to include a reference to that binary with some forced stack alignment to avoid SSE related segfaulting (call it `foo.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void multi(const char *caller) {
    printf("called from %s\n", caller);
}

__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer))
void multi_main(void) {
    multi(__FILE__);
    exit(42);
}

const char dl_loader[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) =
    "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2";
```

- compile/link the library with its *runnable* entry point defined:

```
$ gcc -fPIC -shared -o foo.so foo.c --entry=multi_main
$ ldd foo.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff345d7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5bd69f6000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5bd6be9000)
$ file foo.so 
foo.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=94ffcc60e66b21021ad564882c8e39ebeccd477e, not stripped
$ ./foo.so 
called from foo.c
```

This is a fairly minimal example. You can find more detail in my previous answer, or the linked commits against [`libcap`](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/).